# No response when making REST request is tested on rest client in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

No response when making REST request is tested on rest client in Apache Camel
I am newbie and working with Apache Camel and RESTful services. When I make request with url, I am getting

CamelHttpTransportServlet - No consumer to service request org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade
This is my some content of web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>Camel Http Transport Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>ignoreDuplicateServletName</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

This is the code for my RouteBuilder

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    restConfiguration().component("servlet").contextPath("/my").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.off).endpointProperty("servletName", "myServlet");

        rest("/card").post("/load")
            .type(CardActRequest.class)
            .to("direct:load");

         onException(Exception.class)
        .handled(true)
        .bean(CardRequestResponse, "createErrorResponse");

         from("direct:load")
         .process(CardRequestResponse)
         .bean(CardRequestResponse, "processRequest") 
            .choice()
                .when(simple("${body} != null"))
                    .to("stream:out")
                    .bean(CardRequestResponse, "processResponse").endChoice()
                .otherwise()
                    .bean(CardRequestResponse, "createErrorResponse");

    }
```

Now when I make the request in following order:
http://localhost:8080/my/card/load

Comment: Ok but do you even receive the request in Camel or where in that flow does it fail? You sure the camel context and route are up and running?

Comment: I think you need to use CamelServlet as the servlet name

Comment: I am new to camel so I dont understand what you are saying but I have installed jboss- tooling iin eclipse mars and deploying project in JBOSS EAP 6.4

Comment: import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.cdi.ContextName;
import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;Startup
ApplicationScoped
ContextName("my")
public class CardRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
 @Inject
  private CardRequestResponseHandler cardRequestResponse;